# Java explanation to code output using constructors and "this"

Tags: java, object, constructor, tostring

```
public class potpie {
    public int month;
    public int day;
    public int year;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    potpie potObject = new potpie(4,5,6);
}

public potpie(int m, int d, int y){
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;

    System.out.printf("The constructor for this is %s\n", this);
}


public String toString(){
    return String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year);
}
}
```

I am watching a video tutorial on java, and he writes this code. But I do not understand his explanation to why it prints out

```
The constructor for this is 4/5/6
```

I just do not see why the method toString is used?

Comment: This is because `System.out.printf("...%s\n", this);` is equivalent to `System.out.printf("...%s\n", this.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` located inside the the constructor refers to the current object "being constructed", a `potpie`.

The **sysout** function automatically calls the toString() method on the passed in object. If the object's class does not override the `toString` method, you may get the `Object` version which looks like `"classname@HexNumber"`.

```
// Behind the scenes
System.out.printf("The constructor for this is %s\n", this.toString());
```

Comment: How sysout function automatically called toString() method?

Comment: The **sysout** calls the `toString` method on the passed in object to convert it to its string representation.

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is called by the API itself during the call to [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) because you specified the `%s` identifier in the format String.

```
System.out.printf("The constructor for this is %s\n", this);
                                               ^^
```

This method uses the class `Formatter` to format the output and quoting [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for the `%s` identifier (emphasis mine):

> If the argument `arg` is `null`, then the result is `"null"`. If `arg` implements `Formattable`, then `arg.formatTo` is invoked. **Otherwise, the result is obtained by invoking `arg.toString()`**.

Answer (score 1):

when you override `toString` method in a class. it called `toString` method on contruct object that class.

If you don't override it, The output is, class name, then ‘at’ sign, and at the end hashCode of object contruct object like

```
The default toString() method in Object prints “class name @ hash code"
```

As here you print:

```
System.out.printf("The constructor for this is %s\n", this);
```

this call toString:

```
String.format("%d/%d/%d", month, day, year)
```

your output like:
 `System.out.printf("The constructor for this is %s\n", {toString call});`

Finally,

```
The constructor for this is 4/5/6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
potpie potObject = new potpie(4,5,6);
```

it will Call `public potpie(int m, int d, int y)` method with value (4,5,6);

then assign the value of m,d and y to month,day,year varriable 
this is used for call current `object` of class,method etc

then they write `toString()` method to format month date and year .
it will be format with `%d` that return `/date/month/year` .

- the default `toString()` method contain  “classname @ hash code of class" like test@45689.